# How can I calculate new time zone in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone, gmt

Lets say I have a time 04:05 and the timezone is -0100 (GMT)

I want to calculate the new time which will be 03:05

Is there any function in python to do that calculcation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
   >>> import datetime
   >>> my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('04:05', '%H:%M')
   >>> my_time
   datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 4, 5)
   >>> offset_str = '-0100'
   >>> offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(offset_str.lstrip('-')[:2]), minutes=int(offset_str.lstrip('-')[2:])) * (-1 if offset_str.startswith('-') else 1)
   >>> offset 
   datetime.timedelta(-1, 82800)
   >>> my_time + offset
   datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 3, 5)
   >>> (my_time + offset).time()
   datetime.time(3, 5)
```

In short:

```
   >>> import datetime
   >>> my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('04:05', '%H:%M')
   >>> offset_str = '-0100'
   >>> offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(offset_str.lstrip('-')[:2]), minutes=int(offset_str.lstrip('-')[2:])) * (-1 if offset_str.startswith('-') else 1)
   >>> (my_time + offset).time()
   datetime.time(3, 5)
```

Comment: 10x! that will do the job,but can any one can think of a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "pytz" to accomplish this.Try:

```
from string import atoi
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # Available http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=79122

thedate = "20080518"
thetime = "2210"

europe_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris') # Note that your local install timezone should be settings.py
brazil_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
server_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')

stat_time = datetime(atoi(thedate[0:4]), atoi(thedate[4:6]), atoi(thedate[6:8]), atoi(thetime[0:2]), atoi(thetime[2:4]), 0, tzinfo=europe_tz)

stat_time.astimezone(brazil_tz) # returns time for brazil
stat_time.astimezone(server_tz) # returns server time
```

Source: http://menendez.com/blog/python-timezone-conversion-example-using-pytz/

Comment: its not good for me, i got 2 strigns-"04:05" and "-0100" and and i whant to use them to calc the new time but 10x!!